# 14.04 freezes after splash | Immediately after installing updates

Tags: boot, 14.04, freeze

Laptop is a Dell XPS 14 (L421x).  i7 3517u with Nvidia GT630m, 14.04 LTS.  I am using Intel graphics drivers for Linux, I don't remember if I used Nvidia drivers or not.

Got prompted for updates last night using GUI, went ahead and installed.  Prompted for a reboot, rebooted.  Boots as follows:

1. Computer boots without issues.  Grub & Linux are both installed on SDB (mSata).  Boot to mSata.
2. Grub loads just fine.  Select Ubuntu, either of the two kernels.
3. Ubuntu splash screen comes up briefly.
4. System freezes on an all black screen with half of a solid cursor in the very top left corner.  Can't even get into a console, will only respond to power button.

I can get into recovery mode, but I'm not to sure what I'm doing beyond things like looking for broken packages of which there are none.

Searching for Ubuntu won't boot leads to 101 posts on reinstalling grub, but I'm still looking.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And problem appears to have been Nvidia drivers, 334.

Fixed using these steps at recovery console.

```
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
apt-get install unity
apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
shutdown -r now
```